# How to pull from private docker repository on docker hub?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I create a automated build repository on dockerhub (via github) and try to pull the image which is automatically built onto cloud server.

using things like

docker pull com.company/project:tag

but it gives me

```
Error: image com.company/project:tag not found
```

it usually works for public repository, do I have to do something else for private repository ?

Comment: Sounds like you need to setup a private Docker registry to host your built images. In other words do a "docker push" before you can do a "docker pull"

Comment: solved by meself, "docker login" is needed for authentication

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You just need to use the command **docker login** with your sign parameters from docker hub.

Answer (score 13):

Another way to do this is to create a docker `config.json` file. The file should be placed in `~/.docker/config.json` and the Docker Hub authorization token can be specified in the file.

```
{
    "auths": {
        "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
            "auth": "my-docker-hub-generated-auth-token"
        }
    }
}
```

This is a useful strategy if you are working with servers that need the ability to run scripts that pull images from Docker Hub.

**Resources and further infomration:**

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#privileged-user-requirement
- [docker unauthorized: authentication required - upon push with successful login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36663742/docker-unauthorized-authentication-required-upon-push-with-successful-login)

Comment: The current implementation is `base64("username:token")`. Using `docker login registry.url.here -uusername -p` should generate the correct data.