# docker unauthorized: authentication required - upon push with successful login

Tags: docker

While pushing the docker image (after successful login) from my host I am getting "unauthorized: authentication required".

Details below.

```
-bash-4.2# docker login --username=asamba --email=anand.sambamoorthy@gmail.com
WARNING: login credentials saved in /root/.docker/config.json
*Login Succeeded*
-bash-4.2#
-bash-4.2# docker push asamba/docker-whale

Do you really want to push to public registry? [y/n]: y
The push refers to a repository [docker.io/asamba/docker-whale] (len: 0)
faa2fa357a0e: Preparing
unauthorized: authentication required
```

- Docker version: 1.9.1 (both client and server)
- http://hub.docker.com has the repo created as well (asamba/docker-whale).

The /var/log/messages shows 403, I dont know if this docker. See below.

```
Apr 16 11:39:03 localhost journal: time="2016-04-16T11:39:03.884872524Z" level=info msg="{Action=push, Username=asamba, LoginUID=1001, PID=2125}"
Apr 16 11:39:03 localhost journal: time="2016-04-16T11:39:03.884988574Z" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.21/images/asamba/docker-whale/push returned error: Error: Status 403 trying to push repository asamba/docker-whale to official registry: needs to be forced"
Apr 16 11:39:03 localhost journal: time="2016-04-16T11:39:03.885013241Z" level=error msg="HTTP Error" err="Error: Status 403 trying to push repository asamba/docker-whale to official registry: needs to be forced" statusCode=403
Apr 16 11:39:05 localhost journal: time="2016-04-16T11:39:05.420188969Z" level=info msg="{Action=push, Username=asamba, LoginUID=1001, PID=2125}"
Apr 16 11:39:06 localhost kernel: XFS (dm-4): Mounting V4 Filesystem
Apr 16 11:39:06 localhost kernel: XFS (dm-4): Ending clean mount
Apr 16 11:39:07 localhost kernel: XFS (dm-4): Unmounting Filesystem
```

Any help is appreciated, please let me know if you need further info. I did the push with -f as well. No luck!

Comment: [Beware token timeouts.](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33558)

Comment: Make sure your local version of Docker is up-to-date. I had this same issue and the problem was my machine was running a (embarrassingly) old version of Docker. The login command claimed to succeed, but no push. Upgrading to the latest resolved the issue.

Comment: After hours of struggle I found the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76695342/5465632) and have added here.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

OK! never mind; I found the solution. with 403 Suspected that the HTTP is not going to the right URL.

Change the file which has the login credentials stored the `~/.docker/config.json` from the default generated of

```
{
        "auths": {
                "docker.io": {
                        "auth": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                        "email": "x.y@gmail.com"
                }
        }
}
```

to - Note the change from docker.io -> index.docker.io/v1. That is the change.

```
{
        "auths": {
                "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
                        "auth": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                        "email": "x.y@gmail.com"
                }
        }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Note that the auth field should be 'username:password" base64 encoded.
for example: "username:password" base64 encoded is "dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ="

so your file would contain:

```
"auth": "dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ="
```

Comment: You saved me quite some time! Perfect solution for me as well.

Comment: Worked for me as well. Here is the same thing from the command line: `sudo docker login -e me@example.com  -u someuser -p somepass https://index.docker.io/v1/`

Comment: Thanks @Banjer, the -e param is deprecated though, and sudo shouldn't have to be used for most who got their system set up properly. A better solution would be: `docker login -u someuser https://index.docker.io/v1/`
This will ask for the password, preventing it from ending up in command history.

Answer (score 113):

You'll need to log in to Docker.

### Step 1: log in to docker hub

Based on @KaraPirinc's comment, in Docker version 17 in order to log in:

```
docker login -u username --password-stdin
```

Then enter your password when asked.

### Step 2: create a repository in the [docker hub](https://cloud.docker.com/).

Let's say "**mysqlserver:sql**".

```
docker push <user username>/mysqlserver:sql
```

Comment: **This should be the correct answer**. `docker login` also works without the params

Comment: Works perfectly.  However, **--email has been deprecated**.

Comment: (docker version 17) :  docker login -u username -p password

Comment: thanks for the update. I will update the answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 34):

The solution you posted is not working for me...

This is what works for me:

1. Create the repository with the desired name.
2. When committing the image, name the image like the repository, including the username `<dockerusername>/desired-name`. For example, `radu/desired-name`.

Comment: # docker ps -a get name of conainer --nostalgic_morse here
# docker commit -m "test" -a "alex" nostalgic_morse alexcpn/grpc
# docker push alexcpn/grpc

Answer (score 33):

The problem newbies face is that we tend to treat docker hub repository just like a maven repository and think that it might contain many a different files, folders and other contents. 
A docker repository on the other hand is just a single image, it does not contain anything else. It can hold different versions of the same image, but its going to contain just one image.
So, name your repository on docker hub the same name as the image you want to push into it, and use your dockerhub username as prefix. For eg, if your username is *myusername* and your image name is *docker-whale* , make sure to name your dockerhub repository as *docker-whale* and use the below commands to tag and push your image to repository:

```
docker logout                                   # to make sure you're logged out and not cause any clashes
docker tag <imageId> myusername/docker-whale    # use :1.0.0 for specific version, default is 'latest'
docker login --username=myusername              # use the username/pwd to login to docker hub
docker push myusername/docker-whale             # use :1.0.0 for pushing specific version, default is 'latest'
```

Comment: I kept getting "denied: requested access to the resource is denied" until I saw this post. Finally, managed to get my first ever "docker-push" to work without being hand-held by a tutorial. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: saved the essence of this hint here: https://github.com/asmexcaliburwoods/flowerdocumentationscents/commit/e5d1b36723c192a72c575b74611422605ada2c90#diff-073cf5ff82dcece0ab91634f200d2412ca72b21e29ad1dc02cbf61c12fc19c7a

Comment: lol I use my nick name as my dockerhub username, but I must be tired and keep using my work alias. DoH!

Answer (score 28):

if you are using heroku, be sure you did not forget to "heroku container:login" before pushing.

Comment: Also make sure you tagged the application with the right name, i.e. the name of the heroku app.  I had replaced a dash with an underscore in my docker image tag, and kept getting an unauthorized error trying to push it to the heroku registry.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem but i fixed it with push with specified url.
as: docker login -u  https://index.docker.io/v1/

console output:

```
The push refers to a repository [docker.io/<username>/richcity]
adc9144127c1: Preparing 
4db5654f7a64: Preparing 
ce71ae73bc60: Preparing 
e8e980243ee4: Preparing 
d773e991f7d2: Preparing 
bae23f4bbe95: Waiting 
5f70bf18a086: Waiting 
3d3e4e34386e: Waiting 
e72d5d9d5d30: Waiting 
8d1d75696199: Waiting 
bdf5b19f60a4: Waiting 
c8bd8922fbb7: Waiting 
unauthorized: authentication required

1010deiMac:dockerspace whoami$ docker login -u <username> https://index.docker.io/v1/
Password: 
Login Succeeded
1010deiMac:dockerspace whoami$ docker push <username>/richcity 
The push refers to a repository [docker.io/<username>/richcity]
adc9144127c1: Pushed 
4db5654f7a64: Pushed 
ce71ae73bc60: Pushed 
e8e980243ee4: Pushed 
d773e991f7d2: Pushed 
bae23f4bbe95: Pushed 
5f70bf18a086: Pushed 
3d3e4e34386e: Pushing [=============>                                     ] 45.07 MB/165.4 MB
e72d5d9d5d30: Pushed 
8d1d75696199: Pushing [>                                                  ] 1.641 MB/118.1 MB
bdf5b19f60a4: Pushing [============>                                      ]   142 MB/568.4 MB
c8bd8922fbb7: Pushing [========================>                          ] 59.44 MB/121.8 MB
```

Answer (score 8):

I was running into a similar issue with a similarly unhelpful error message, but it turned out to be because I was trying to push an image that I had built against a docker-machine managed instance.

When I logged into the instance itself, did `docker login` and `docker push` everything worked fine.

Comment: thanks, the docker login automatically creates the config file like described at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36664163/1240337)

Answer (score 8):

In case it helps anyone, I managed to resolve this with the following command at the prompt:

```
az acr login -n MyContainerName
```

After this, I could run `docker push` successfully.

Comment: Worked for me. It is specific to `acr`.

Answer (score 6):

Though the standard process is to login and then push to docker registry, trick to get over this particular problem is to login by providing username and password in same line.

So :

```
docker login -u xxx -p yyy sampledockerregistry.com/myapp 
docker push sampledockerregistry.com/myapp
```

**Works**

whereas

```
docker login sampledockerregistry.com 
username : xxx
password : yyy
Login Succeeded

docker push sampledockerregistry.com/myapp
```

**Fails**

Answer (score 4):

Even I logged in and checked all the configuration, it still does not work !!!

It turned out that when I build my docker, I forget to put my username before the repo name

```
docker build docker-meteor-build
```

(build successfully)

And then when I pushed to my repository, I used

```
docker push myname/docker-meteor-build
```

It will show the `unauthorized authentication required`

So, solution is then name of build and the push should be exactly the same

```
docker build myname/docker-meteor-build 
docker push myname/docker-meteor-build
```

Answer (score 3):

Here the solution for my case ( private repos, free account plan)

https://success.docker.com/Datacenter/Solve/Getting_%22unauthorized%3A_authentication_required%22_when_trying_to_push_image_to_DTR

The image build name to push has to have the same name of the repos.

Example:
repos on docker hub is: accountName/resposName
image build name "accountName/resposName" -> docker build -t accountName/resposName

then type
docker push accountName/resposName:latest

That's all.

Comment: Link is now broken.  Please fix it.

Answer (score 3):

My problem was an invalid Authorization token after 5 minutes.
The push took more than 5 minutes because of the image size.

I've fixed it by increasing the "Authorization token duration" to 10 minutes.

[image]

Comment: Where did you find this setting? I couldn't find it.

Comment: My hack to avoid this problem was to run `docker login` in another terminal window shortly before upload finished

Comment: @VicSeedoubleyew `Admin Area -> Settings -> CI/CD -> Container Registry`. 
url path: `/admin/application_settings/ci_cd`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Admin area of what? I don't see any of that on dockerhub

Comment: That is for a own gitlab instance. I'm not sure if you can configure that on dockerhub.

Answer (score 2):

If you are pushing a new private image for the first time, make sure your subscription supports this extra image.

Docker allows you to have 6 private images named, even if you only pay for 5, but not to push that 6th image. The lack of an informative message is confusing and irritating.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was to create a new repository and rename the image with

`$ docker tag image_id myname/server:latest`

Answer (score 2):

Try `docker logout` first, then relogin with `docker login`

Answer (score 2):

This error seem to also appear if your system's date/time/timezone are not set correctly. To fix, ensure your system time settings are correct.

Comment: This seemed to work for me. Here is the full steps I took before I made a successful push. (Using a Windows 10 machine and docker v4.27.1):
1. Log out of docker from the cli: `docker logout`
2. Set date/time/timezone of my system correctyl.
3. Sign in to docker hub account on docker desktop.
4. Go to the images tab and use the controls on each image to push to docker hub.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have more slots for private images.

In my case I converted a user into an organization and it lost it's one free private image, so previous pushes that worked, no longer worked.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here, during pushing image:

```
unauthorized: authentication required
```

What I did:

```
docker login --username=yourhubusername --email=youremail@company.com
```

Which it printed:

> --email is deprecated (but login succeeded still)

Solution: use the latest login syntax.

```
docker login
```

It will ask for both ***username*** and ***password*** interactively.  Then the image push just works.

Even after using the new syntax, my `~/.docker/config.json` looks like this after logged in:

```
{
    "auths": {
        "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {}
    },
    "credsStore": "osxkeychain"
}
```

So the credential is in macOS' keychain.

Answer (score 1):

You can mv the xxx/.docker/config.json file somewhere for handle it.
Then try to login again for create new config.json file.

```
#mv xx/.docker/config.json xx/.docker/config_old.json
#docker login https://index.docker.io/v1/
Login with your Docker ID to push and pull images from Docker Hub. If you don't have a Docker ID, head over to https://hub.docker.com to create one.
Username: YOUR USERNAME
Password: YOUR PASSWORD
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /xxx/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/hadolint/hadolint/manifests/latest: unauthorized: incorrect username or password
```

I found out out that even if I login successfully with the `docker login` command, any pull failed.
I tried to clean up the `~/.docker/config.json` but nothing improved.

Looking in the config file I've seen that the credentials were not saved there but in a `"credsStore": "secretservice"`.
In Linux this happen to be the `seahorse` or `Passwords and Keys` tool.
I checked there and I cleanup all the docker hub login.
After this a new docker login worked as expected.

Comment: What command did you run to clean up all docker hub login from password managers?

Comment: @CBBSpike I just opened the Password manager and deleted the docker credentials from there.

Answer (score 1):

Its the problem with the proxy.

Turn off the VPN if you are working on  any.

https://forums.docker.com/t/failed-with-status-401-unauthorized/11023/3

Answer (score 0):

in your configuration file ~/.docker/config.json add

```
{
        "auths": {
             "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
                        "auth": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                        "email": "my_email@gmail.com"
                }
        }
}
```

where XXXXX is base64 encoding of your **username:password**  (the : is included) of https://hub.docker.com

in my case i had the same error with a pull. the problem (under windows) was provoked by double docker running process, so a kill them all and restart one service and it works .

Answer (score 0):

I have received similar error for sudo docker push /sudo docker pull on ecr repository.This is because aws cli installed in my user(abc) and docker installed in root user.I have tried to run sudo docker push on my user(abc)

Fixed this by installed aws cli in root , configured aws using aws configure in root and run sudo docker push to ecr on root user

Answer (score 0):

If you running  `windows 7 docker Registry`

1. Start  `**Docker Quick Start terminal**` run (this terminal enables  connection ) Until you pushed images ,  that will keep token alive .
2. Login 
   `docker login`
3. Make sure you tag the image with username

   `docker build -f Dockerfile -t 'username'/imagename`
4. push image

   `docker image push username/imagename`

**Note**: image name all lowercase

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the methods I can find online and failed. Then I read this post and get some ideas from @Alex answer. Then I search about ""credsStore": "osxkeychain"" which is used in my config.json. The I follow this link https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/ to logout and then login again. Finally, I can push my image successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I can fix it.
change the `~/.docker/config.json` file as below

```
{
    "auths": {
        "XxX": {
            "auth": "XxX"
        }
    }
}
```

and do not forget to restart docker service.

```
service docker restart
```

enjoy

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same problem with Heroku and Docker, the solution was

```
docker login
docker build . -t <project_name> 
heroku container:login
heroku container:push web -a <project_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I fixed it with push with a specified URL:

```
docker login -u https://index.docker.io/v1/
```

Just curious to know what could be the cause for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Old post but had same issue and couldn't find the answer.
NOTE: the Docker tag is case sensitive to Azure loginserver name.

I was uploading to Azure container. Container was named "LearnContainer81"
Loginserver was "learncontainer81.azurecr.io"

When I did the tag in Docker, I did it with "LearnContainer81.azurecr.io/X" and it gives *unauthorised*. Did tag again in lowercase as per Loginserver for Azure. This then uploaded fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using my self-hosted docker registry, where I terminate HTTPS/SSL first on another server (such as nginx or trafficserver), and then pass the traffic to registry over non-encrypted HTTP. After a lot of research, I managed to get it to work.

i) the problem is caused by not having X-Forwarded-Proto -header set in PATCH -requests, resulting in 401 error. See https://github.com/distribution/distribution/issues/1177#issuecomment-155718420

ii) nginx version 18 (and lower such as Ubuntu Bionic and Focal) seems not to pass the

```
proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto https;
```

for PATCH (POST works ok), but nginx version 21 works ok.

Also Apache Trafficserver seems to pass the headers properly, once enabled.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was pushing to an image registry that was a part of **OpenShift**,
I was logged in, but I didn't have access to the `ImageStream` resource type.

So I logged in with another token that had enough privileges and the problem solved.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your docker repositry name matches your local docker repo name.
e.g lets say if you local repo name "kavashgar/nodjsapp"

then your should also have a repo names "kavashgar" in docker hub

Answer (score -1):

There has already been good answers but I would like to mention one - **You do NOT need to create a repository in advance before pushing it.**

The problem for me was that I didn't set the correct username of the account I logged in to. But once the correct username is set before the image (e.g. `YOURNAME/YOURIMAGE`) via its tag, you can push it without creating a new repository in advance.

```
sudo docker tag IMAGE:VERSION USERNAME/IMAGE:VERSION
sudo docker push USERNAME/IMAGE:VERSION
```