# docker: unauthorized: authentication required

Tags: docker

I am trying to download and start a docker container like this:

```
docker run -it -p 8000:8000 -p 8060:8060 -h sandbox somegithubrepo bash
```

However, the downloading stops midway and I get this:

```
docker: unauthorized: authentication required.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

So I looked here:
[docker unauthorized: authentication required - upon push with successful login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36663742/docker-unauthorized-authentication-required-upon-push-with-successful-login)

I tried this:

```
docker push  mydockerhubusername/somerepo:latest
```

But I'm getting:

```
The push refers to a repository [docker.io/mydockerhubusername/somerepo]
An image does not exist locally with the tag: mydockerhubusername/somerepo
```

My `~/.docker/config.json` looks like this:

```
{
        "auths": {
                "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
                        "auth": "someKey"
                }
        }
}
```

So how can I download the container?

Comment: For downloading public **docker** repositories, you don't need to be logged in. Please try just pulling the repository with `docker pull reponame`, where `reponame` is something listed at https://hub.docker.com/. Could you please provide some more details on the image you want to download and run?

Comment: you seem to confuse `docker push` and `docker pull`, the first you put on the Docker hub a docker image you have created (and you need to login), the last one you copy a docker image from the Docker hub to your host

Answer (score 0):

You don't download a container. You download an image, and then do a `docker run` on that image which then starts a container. For that to happen, the image has to exist somewhere - either in some Docker registry like the public [DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/) or your private registry or your local machine. If it doesn't exist on your local machine, `docker run` tries to `docker pull` it from DockerHub by default, or from the private registry if you're logged into one.

If you want to push the image from your local machine to a registry, you'll have to log into that registry on your machine, create a repository, build the image, and then `docker push` the image to that repository so that you can download it from somewhere else and start a container. Of course, to build an image, you'll need a Dockerfile, or some plugin in your project which builds it automatically for you.

Ex: Java image has already been published and I don't have it on my machine, so when I do `docker run java`, it starts to `docker pull` the image from the [official DockerHub repository](https://hub.docker.com/_/java/):

```
~ $: docker run java
Unable to find image 'java:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/java
386a066cd84a: Pull complete
...
...
...
Status: Downloaded newer image for java:latest
```