# denied: requested access to the resource is denied: docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am following [this link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted/step_four/) to create my first docker Image and it went successfully and now I am trying to push this Image into my docker repository from this [link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted/step_six/). But whenever I am trying to push this Image into repository, I  got this type of error.

```
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

[image]

Note: I have successfully login into docker

Comment: Make sure you are not making this mistake: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59626146/4954434

Comment: Make sure you confirm your email. If you are thinking who would do such a stupid thing, I did not confirm my email before pushing.

Comment: This one works for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42300879/3333878

Comment: check if you need `sudo`

Answer (score 1269, accepted):

You may need to switch your docker repo to private before docker push.

Thanks to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42403423/4096935) provided by [Dean Wu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7607604/dean-wu) and [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984399/denied-requested-access-to-the-resource-is-denied-docker/41984666#comment94770203_41984666) by [ses](https://stackoverflow.com/users/369759/ses), before pushing, remember to **log out**, then **log in** from the command line to your docker hub account

```
# you may need log out first `docker logout` ref. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53835882/248616
docker login
```

According to the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted/step_six/#/step-1-tag-and-push-the-image):

```
You need to include the namespace for Docker Hub to associate it with your account.
The namespace is the same as your Docker Hub account name.
You need to rename the image to YOUR_DOCKERHUB_NAME/docker-whale.
```

So, this means you have to **tag** your image before pushing:

```
docker tag firstimage YOUR_DOCKERHUB_NAME/firstimage
```

and then you should be able to push it.

```
docker push YOUR_DOCKERHUB_NAME/firstimage
```

Comment: Not for me. I've tried all combinations of `[host]/[namespace]/[repo]` and still the same error (meaning, i have organizations and my account as the namespace). Even tried `docker login ...`. I can't push :-|

Comment: hii i follow your command got Error ---Error response from daemon: No such image: ubuntu-nodejs:latest

Comment: This answer should not have been marked as accepted! The solution provided clearly does not work as others have indicated.

Comment: I had the same issue and it turned out that I was not logged in properly. "docker login" behaves awkwardly, it showed "login succeeded" even when I entered wrong password. So to login appropriately, I used "docker login <url> --username=<username>". Post this, "docker push" worked as expected.

Comment: This answer is not complete and didn't work for me. Venu S provided a complete answer which solved this problem for me.

Comment: I think its better to follow the official instructions: https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/builds/push-images/ for me I did not do the `docker login` command and thats why it was not working for me.

Comment: Not sure if this could help you guys. I have created a repository on Docker Cloud yoursername/netcoreapplicacion1, go to console, `docker login`, locally tag from your local app to remote `docker tag netcorewebapplication1:dev yoursername/netcorewebapplication1` and finally `docker push yourusername/netcorewebapplication1`.

Comment: Make sure the usernames match

Comment: Thnx Man. Solved my issue. I put my own DockerHub name , when I tried to Build and Push to DocketHub.

Comment: haha. I would help tons of ppl if you put "docker login" to the beginning of the answer.

Comment: you get the EXACT same error if you try pushing to a private docker hub organization that doesn't have any more repo slots for your price plan

Comment: I had to do dockerUserName/dockerRepoName:dockerImageTagName because doing as you suggest didn't work : dockerUserName/dockerRepoName/dockerImageTagName

Comment: Thanks man! Straight forward solution. 
I am using `Docker Desktop - Version 2.0.0.3 (31259)`. Even though the docker is showing running, my user account is not actually signed in with the dockerhub account. After signing in, the push worked for me. I think the status is about the `Docker Desktop suite running locally`.

Comment: For those running into issues. It's possible you need to explicitly add the port number in your docker login command, ie `docker login <private-repo-host>:<port>` as `docker login` or `docker login <private-repo-host>` may connect without issue, but when it comes time to push images, you'll get the same error as OP.

Comment: `sudo docker login`

AND enable X11 forwarding if you're on ssh

Comment: `docker image tag --help` would give you the answer on what exactly should do:

 ```Usage: docker image tag SOURCE_IMAGE[:TAG] TARGET_IMAGE[:TAG]

    Create a tag TARGET_IMAGE that refers to SOURCE_IMAGE``` 

and of course use `docker logout` and `docker login` accordingly.

Comment: This worked for me whithout changing the repo to private

Comment: this is annoying. Why do I need to do this if I already logged in with docker login?

Comment: Logout then login fixed my issue.

Answer (score 307):

I had the same issue, but accepted answer given here did not work for me.
I tried few steps and was able to get around to push it finally.

Here are the steps worked for me:

1. Login to the docker.

   `docker login -u darlin`
2. Tag your image build

my image name here is **mylocalimage** and by default it has tag **latest**
and my username is **darlin** as registered with docker cloud, and I created a public repository named **dockerhub**

so my personal repository becomes now **darlin/dockerhub**
and I want to push my image with tag `myfirstimagepush`.

I tagged as below :

```
docker tag mylocalimage:latest darlin/dockerhub:myfirstimagepush
```

3. Pushed the image to my personal docker repository as below

   `docker push darlin/dockerhub:myfirstimagepush`

And it was successfully pushed to my personal docker repo.

Comment: This answer solved my problem. This should be the accepted answer. The other answer is not complete and did not work for me. For example, the other answer makes no mention of `docker login`. Until coming to this thread, I didn't know about `docker login`.

Comment: in general you should be using sudo prefixing all your commands ref http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/08/why-we-dont-let-non-root-users-run-docker-in-centos-fedora-or-rhel/

Comment: Caveat with sudo - see my answer

Comment: One change i recommend is to use common names like "john","bob" or "alice" instead of complicated names. But nice answer!

Comment: Solved it for me too but why? I mean why does this work?

Comment: This works for me. it looks like we need to tag it as mentioned before push.

Answer (score 247):

I got the same issue while taking the docker beginner Course. I solved the issue by doing a`docker login` before the docker push call.

Comment: FWIW, I was getting  _error getting credentials_ on `docker login`.  `sudo docker login` worked for me.  This allowed me to push my private repo.

Comment: Apparently the Docker webinar is outdated.

Comment: Caveat with sudo - see my answer

Comment: I did `docker login` AND tagged my local image with `docker tag ubuntu franva/ubuntu`, then I ran `docker push franva/ubuntu`

Comment: Must use ASL logging (which requires CGO) if running as root
Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `

Comment: FWIW, on my shared dev server the root user was logged in as a different user from someone else, so `sudo docker push` would try to push to the other user's account. Running `docker push` would instead use 'my' docker hub account.

Answer (score 73):

Use Below commands:

```
$ docker login
<enter user name and password for Docker Hub Repository>

$ docker tag first-image {docker-hub-username}/{default-repo-folder-name}:first-image

$ docker push {docker-hub-username}/{default-repo-folder-name}:first-image
```

e.g. I have public repository like manjeet86/docker-repo so commands would be:

```
$ docker tag first-image manjeet86/docker-repo:first-image

$ docker push manjeet86/docker-repo:first-image
```

Just see `:` instead of `/` that was the trick. It works for me. I do not know if it lets you tag with `/` as well in place of `:` but that may be for some other purpose.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/#examples

Comment: This is what worked for me, using `:` instead of `/`, thanks.

Comment: Possible explanation for the issue in this thread : 
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31760#issuecomment-309812486

Comment: This was the only answer that solved for me.

Answer (score 56):

Important also to note is that when you tag your image, you tag it using the **Namespace** and then your repository / **mydevrepo**. This confused me when following the Docker docs. After that I used:

```
docker login
```

And then I pushed my Image using the *'tagged name'*.

```
docker push {namespace}/mydevrepo
```

Comment: In other words do something like `{namespace}/wordpress-cli-ansible` and not `{namespace}/wordpress-helm/wordpress-cli-ansible`. That's one issue I was having which was preventing me from pushing.

Answer (score 27):

Here is a work-around as of January, 2018:

1. Go to `hub.docker.com` and change your repository to private
2. In your shell run:

   `docker images`

   > `REPOSITORY              TAG       IMAGE ID         CREATED           SIZE verse_gapminder_gsl     latest    023ab91c6291     3 minutes ago     1.975 GB verse_gapminder         latest    bb38976d03cf     13 minutes ago    1.955 GB rocker/verse            latest    0168d115f220     3 days ago        1.954 GB`

   `docker tag bb38976d03cf dockhubusername/verse_gapminder:mytag`

   `docker login docker.io`

   `docker push dockhubusername/verse_gapminder:mytag`
3. Go back to docker hub and change the repository back to public.

Comment: #without the specific login command above, kept getting access error when pushing,  even though i had logged in via command line

Comment: first login then use these commands it will work definitely $ docker image tag nginx my-user-name/nginx  
$ docker image push my-user-name/nginx:latest

Answer (score 23):

I was facing the same issue, I was giving my image name as `something/image-name` but instead I tried with `<docker-hub-username>/image-name` and it worked like a charm.

**Step 1**

`docker login --username=jp9573`

**Step 2**

`docker push jp9573/todo`

Earlier I was giving `jaypatel/todo`, I just changed it to the `username/image` pattern. In this way, I don't have to tag the image or anything. I think it's a good way for a newcomer.

Comment: Tried all possible things and this simple username worked like a charm

Answer (score 22):

I was with this issue too, I tested the solutions in here present but to no avail, I was properly logged in, at least according to the output of `docker login` but still I could not push the image. What finally worked was simply to do:

`docker logout`

And then `docker login` again, it was that trivial. I'm not sure what happened but forcing the re-login worked.

Comment: Yeah with logout, it comes back working for me. Thank you!

Comment: Nope, logout does not work for me. Man, Docker sucks really bad, I can't believe they can't manage to display more of a useful error message, this error message says absolutely nothing, this makes the problem impossible to solve. Debugging on? No difference. Docker is on my list of technologies that need replacing if it can't reliably work.

Answer (score 22):

It worked for me when I used my docker hub name while tagging image. (Here, xyz is a docker hub name)

```
# Login to docker hub account 
docker login 

# tag image 
docker tag nginx xyz/nginx

# push image
docker push xyz/nginx
```

Comment: Worked for me. I didn't tag the image earlier. I thought It does tag automatically since I'm logged in.

Comment: Worked for me. Does the `xyz` have to be your user name on the Docker Hub?

Answer (score 18):

I had the same issue today. The only thing that worked for me was to explicitly login to **"docker.io"**:

```
docker login docker.io
```

I tried various other names, and the login would appear to work, but it would later result in the following error.

> requested access to the resource is denied

Comment: This is also what resolved the issue for me. I tried `docker login` with no success, but the explicit `docker.io` on the end did the trick.

Comment: This was it for me

Comment: explicit login to docker.io did not work for me. Login worked in the past, stopped working now.

Comment: This was the solution for me. But I added double quote. Like this: - docker login -u "username" -p "password" docker.io

Answer (score 16):

My issue was very simply using invalid characters (an extra /) in my image name:

```
myusername/something/image
```

is an invalid image name.  Try myusername/something-image.  Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Such an awful, unspecific error message! I was doing the same thing. Also, it *won't allow repeated special characters*, e.g. **`__`**.

Comment: oy vey. knew that would cause a headache but tried anyway. error was very much a red herring.

Answer (score 14):

Docker also has a limit on the number of private repositories you can have. If you're creating a private repository by pushing from your local machine, it will create the repository but nothing further can be pushed to it or pulled from it, and you'll get the "requested access to the resource is denied" error.

Comment: how to always push as public repo?

Comment: I ran into this too: pushing a new repo resulted in "21/20 private repos". The last repo got into some sort of blocked state: even after reducing the total number of private repos, I kept receiving the access-denied error. I had to delete and re-create the repo.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, maybe embarrassing, but there doesn't seem to be clear documentation on this issue at all: I just signed up for Docker Pro with *private repositories*. I created a private repository, then tried to push to it. Got the dreaded "denied" message.

Pushing to my public repos worked fine, so I knew I was logged in correctly.

After trying everything related to Docker Hub in the prior 30 answers... I finally understood how private repos work: they're the same as public repos, but with an extra step.

---

**When pushing to a repository - ANY repository within a Docker Hub account - you need to prefix the `image:tag` with your username**, eg:

given the following values,

username = yourusername
image name = theimage
tag = thetag

**1)** tag (or commit) the local image, **adding a prefix with your username**:

```
docker tag theimage:thetag yourusername/theimage:thetag
```

*Notes*:

- **if you're in an *organization*, you need to *double prefix* the image** - like so:

```
docker tag theimage:thetag yourusername/yourorganizationname/theimage:thetag
```

- if your tag is `latest`, `:thetag` part can be left out; Docker assumes `:latest` if you don't enter a `:thetag` part

**2)** push the prefixed image to Docker Hub:

```
 docker push yourusername/theimage:thetag
```

*OR*

```
 docker push yourusername/yourorganizationname/theimage:thetag
```

**THE EXTRA STEP:**

***Either***

**before step 1 above, create a private repository in your Docker Hub account.**

Note that the repository name must be the same as `theimage` that you're planning to push. Do not include a `thetag` portion on the repository name. Eg, if your image is `ubuntu:14.04`, you would name your repository `ubuntu`.

***Or***

**if you didn't create the repository in advance (which is not required!):** go to your account in [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/); click on the newly pushed repo, then its Settings tab - and make your repo private.

---

I had seen others with private repos tagging them with the two prefixes, eg `xyz/abc/theimage:thetag`, and I thought the 2nd prefix was something I created to mark the repo as private. Nope - that's only for organizations. Removing any 2nd prefix and setting my repo name as just `theimage` fixed my *denied* error!

Another note: each repo holds all the tagged versions of the images with the given repo's name. So, for example, `ubuntu:latest` and `ubuntu:14.04`, say, will *both* be in the `ubuntu` repo.

*Fun With Docker!*

Comment: this command works for me: docker tag theimage:thetag yourusername/theimage:thetag

Answer (score 13):

The way docker handles user IDs and repositories may be a bit confusing. 
Let's say you create a user account xyz on docker hub. The new account automatically establishes a namespace `xyz`.
Then you create a repository called myrepo. The repository name will actually be `xyz/myrepo`.

To push an image you should do:

```
docker push docker.io/xyz/myrepo
```

You can add ":latest" or a different tag if necessary.

If you get the `requested access to the resource is denied` error message:

1. Go to https://hub.docker.com/ and sign in as xyz.
2. Click on your repository xyz/myrepo.
3. Click on Collaborators.
4. Add xyz as a collaborator.

Comment: so that means we can't push images from a 3rd party public repository?

Answer (score 13):

**OS: Ubuntu16.04**

Reason: I deleted the client config file(**~/.docker/config.json**)

Solution:

- Restart docker.
  **service docker restart**.
- It needs to input Login info, then generates config file automatically.
  **docker login --username=yourdockerhubername --email=youremail@company.com**

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me. I had upgraded my Docker and then for some reason, mvn dockerfile:push failed with this exception. Deleting this config.json fixed it.

Comment: This also helped me. I realized that to login either I should not put the url or if I need to specify docker hub url I should put
`docker login https://index.docker.io/v1/ -u=yourusername`

Answer (score 10):

change the image name to "username"/"image_name"

Comment: yes, it worked for me. need to specify our username in the local image name because this is not git.

Answer (score 7):

If you face this issue while using Azure Container Registry, you can solve it by logging in to your registry first.

```
docker login yourregistry.azurecr.io
```

And then tag your image to match the host name of your registry.

```
docker image tag yourimagename:[version] yourregistry.azurecr.io/yourimagename:[version]
```

And then finally push it.

```
docker push yourregistry.azurecr.io/yourimagename:[version]
```

Comment: Coming from Azure this is what helped! It is not the namespace but the hostname of the registry that is the first part of the tag!

Comment: This was a lifesaver for me.  Many thanks!  I don't know why the Azure quick start steps don't include this.

Answer (score 7):

My answer is related to Azure DevOps similar issues I had with the following common pipeline (it is more specific but it might help somebody save time):

1. Get sources from github
2. Build docker image
3. Push docker image to dockerhub

The error I received at push `denied: requested access to the resource is denied` sent me here.

Please be careful of the variable `$(Build.Repository.Name)` included in your image name. It is by default the name of the repository from github, but for your push to work it should be `dockerhub_account_username/your_dockerhub_repository_name`.

Replace `$(Build.Repository.Name)` with `dockerhub_account_username/your_dockerhub_repository_name` in your image name field for both build and push steps.

This is needed by the dockerhub api to know where to push the image.

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes you may encounter this issue when you are already logged in with another account. In those cases, you will have to:

```
docker logout
```

and then

```
docker login
```

Comment: This appeared to the issue I was facing. Basically I imported the credentials from a different machine using credentials manager and it seems like it didn't worked

Answer (score 7):

```
docker logout
docker login
*(enter username and then password)*
docker login
docker tag {imageName} {dockerUserId}/{imageName}
docker push {dockerUserId}/{imageName}
```

Answer (score 6):

To those trying pushing the image to their own Nexus Repository Manager, do the below:

1) Login to your Nexus Repository Manager (Port 8443 is associated with a specific Docker host Repository)

```
sudo docker login xxx.mydomain.com:8443
```

2) Tag the image WITH YOUR NEXUS SERVER IP/DNS

```
sudo docker tag myimage:latest xxx.mydomain.com:8443/myimage:1.0.0
```

3) Push the image

```
sudo docker push xxx.mydomain.com:8443/myimage:1.0.0
```

Comment: I had an issue in jenkins docker plugin always refering to docker.io. Tagging like xxx.mydomain.com:8443/myimage:1.0.0 solved the issue. Make sure to omit the procotol and /v2/ stuff.

Comment: why to add port. And whose port to add near xxx.mydomain.com. 8443 is fot https spring boot. What if if it is angular application

Comment: @PSatishPatro When your repository resolves to a specific http/https port, tag will need to know where to push it (since you don't actually tell it where to go - as a parameter), as mentioned above, it needs to be the exact url as your full nexus's repository.

Answer (score 6):

It worked after I changed the "**docker login https://hub.docker.com**" to "**docker login docker.io**" and provided username & password.

Then follow below commands:

```
docker tag local-image:tagname new-repo:tagname

docker push new-repo:tagname
```

**NOTE:** "new-repo" will contain "Docker ID + Repo name"

Here I have created "ubuntu" repo in the Docker Hub before running below command.

**Example:**

```
docker tag alok/ubuntu:latest aloktiwari2007/ubuntu:latest

docker push aloktiwari2007/ubuntu:latest
```

Comment: important point for me was tagname in docker tag command it should be following  - <dockeruserid>/<remote repository name>:<tag> . Same tag identifier should be used in push command .

Answer (score 5):

Simple working solution:

Go here `https://hub.docker.com/` to create a PRIVATE repository with name for example `johnsmith/private-repository` this is the `NAME/REPOSITORY` you will use for your image when building the image.

- First, `docker login`
- Second, I use "`docker build -t johnsmith/private-repository:01 .`" to create image, and I use "`docker images`" to confirm the image created such as in this yellow box below: (sorry I can not paste the table format but the text string only)

> johnsmith/private-repository(REPOSITORY) 01(TAD) c5f4a2861d6e(IMAGE ID) 2 days ago(CREATED)  305MB(SIZE)

- Third, I use `docker push johnsmith/private-repository:01`

Done!

Comment: Why a private repo?

Answer (score 5):

Had to tag it with my username like

```
docker login

docker tag imageName username/imageName

docker push username/imageName
```

Only this worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

Login from the app. I've been trying only from terminal with no luck.

This is version 17.06.1

[image]

Comment: On MacOS this was the solution for me.

Answer (score 4):

After docker login, you need name your image with prefix.

e.g. if your username in docker-hub is `Shah`, the image should be:

```
Shah/firstimage
```

Comment: And, it's case-sensitive, so make sure the username is in the right case

Answer (score 3):

I know this question has many answers already, but none of them were helpful to me.

What I observed was that building the image was extremely fast and pushing to docker.io resulted in the error:

```
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

what I also noticed was that doing an

```
docker image ls
```

revealed that the latest build of my image was several days old.

I had to do a

```
docker container prune
```

to get rid of stopped containers, and a

```
docker image prune -a
```

to get rid of old images.
Then I could successfully build and push my image.

The 'denied: requested access to the resource is denied' is not from docker.io, but from local docker. Funny though that it is not failing during build.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. In my case, I was login in index.docker.io and push the image to docker.io/username/image:tag.

The solution is login in the docker.io by run this command:

```
export CI_REGISTRY=docker.io
docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
docker push USERNAME/IMAGE:TAG
```

and the outputs are:

> ```
>  The push refers to repository [docker.io/USERNAME/IMAGE:TAG]
>  eeb7e16c6369: Preparing
>  6bd09f46d0ae: Preparing
>  f5a7f7a3fb28: Preparing
>  07952c1df7f6: Preparing
>  a4522c0d203b: Preparing
>  3e207b409db3: Preparing
>  3e207b409db3: Waiting
>  a4522c0d203b: Layer already exists
>  3e207b409db3: Layer already exists
>  f5a7f7a3fb28: Pushed
>  6bd09f46d0ae: Pushed
>  07952c1df7f6: Pushed
>  eeb7e16c6369: Pushed
>  latest: digest: sha256:7ce256fa83ef1eebcaaaa460c4d73f87f2adf304bc6e6c1b83a19d987cd61ad5
> size: 1579
> Running after_script
> 00:02
> Saving cache
> 00:01
> Uploading artifacts for successful job
> 00:02
>  Job succeeded
> ```

Regards.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me on Windows 10

> docker login

Answer (score 3):

**Have a docker file and requirement is to build an image and push the same to Docker hub immediately**

1. Login to Docker hub 
   sudo docker login -u *your_username*
   Enter password
2. Build the image
   sudo docker build -t *your_username*/demorepo:1.0
   Above, there is no mention of image name as *your_username*/demorepo is a
   repo in docker hub. Tagged name is 1.0
3. Push the image
   sudo docker push *your_username*/demorepo:1.0

**To push already existing image to Docker hub**

1. Login to the Docker hub
   sudo docker login -u *your_username*
   Enter password
2. Tag your image(suppose your image is named as test_docker:1.0) 
   sudo docker tag test_docker:1.0 *your_username*/demorepo:firstpush
   Above, firstpush is the tag name given to your image, test_docker with
   1.0 Tag.
   **IMPORTANT : (While tagging, the image name is not mentioned)**
   Now in docker images you will have 2 images, one says test_docker 1.0 and the other *your_username*/demorepo firstpush
3. Push the image 
   sudo docker push *your_username*/demorepo:firstpush

Answer (score 3):

Many answers talked about login. Of course login is needed, if the error is still not solved after login, look for the ***The push refers to repository***.
In my case, it was trying to push to

> [docker.io/**library**/<myimage>]

After I tagged the repo with `<account_name>/<repo_name>:<tag>` it worked.

```
docker tag mynginx_image:latest <myaccount>/mynginx:latest
docker push <myaccount>/mynginx:latest
```

Then it changed to

> The push refers to repository [docker.io/<myaccount>/mynginx]

Answer (score 3):

For others who have a similar problem (but they are already logged in):

just make sure to rename your tag:

`docker tag whatEverNameForImage:tag YourUserName/whatEverNameForImage:tag`

and then push the latest

```
docker push YourUserName/whatEverNameForImage:tag
```

Comment: This question has over 60 answers. Yours appears to be identical to [this one from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76532853/19068). What makes it worth adding?

Answer (score 2):

I'm also having this issue. Turns out I'm using the free tier and trying to push more than 1 image in the private repository. Making 1 image private and the rest public worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was pushing to an organization where I am in a team that has admin permissions to the repository.

so my push command was:
`docker push org-name/image-name`

I could push successfully to username/image-name but not to the organization. I triple checked the permissions. Nothing worked.

The solution was to delete the repo from docker hub and push again fresh using:
`docker push org-name/image-name`

For what its worth, I think the repo was originally pushed before the account was converted to an organization.

Answer (score 2):

I really hope this helps somebody (who looks to the final answers first as myself):

I continuously tried to type in

```
docker push user/repo/tag
```

Instead

```
docker push user/repo:tag
```

Since I also made my tag like this:

```
docker tag image user/repo/tag
```

...all hell broke lose.

I sincirely hope you don't repeat my mistake. I wasted like 30 mins on this...

Answer (score 2):

I'm slow to add yet another answer, but the accepted answer and remaining answers mentioning `docker login` are missing an edge case to solve the issues others are stating in comments.

```sh
docker login <private-repo-host>:<port>
```

Emphasis on the `port` needing to be entered is likely the solution for those still searching. `docker login` or `docker login <private-repo-host>` may connect without issue, but when it comes time to push images, you'll get the same error as OP.

That is, you can connect w/o defining host or port and still get the:

> ...
>
> Login Succeeded

In my case, I am using a self hosted GitLab's built in docker-registry, which was setup to use port `4567`. It may be adventagous to verify what port the registry must be accessed from. Without specifying said port `docker login <our.gitlab.host>` would login successful, but give the  same issue the OP inquired about:

> ...
>
> The push refers to repository [...]
>
> denied: access forbidden

If you're using docker.io/dockerhub you're likely not going to have this problem, but if you have a self hosted/private registry solution the probability increases you need to explicitly login using both the host and port for the docker registry.

Comment: Thank you, most helpful!

Answer (score 2):

the easiest way is used docker desktop(for Windows 10 or above and mac)

first signup to docker hub by providing dockerID

then click docker desktop icon in your machine and ->Preferences -> then login to it using docker hub docker/id and password.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered this error message, using the Gitlab registry. The difference was that I was attempting to change the name of the image from previous builds. The problem there, is that the registry for the image being pushed did not exist, because the new name of the image didn't match any of the projects in my group.

TLDR: In Gitlab, the image name has to match the project name.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem from `Azure pipeline`. I missed to add `docker-id` in repository section.

From `Azure`, while pushing, if name alone is used e.g. `<repo-name>`, may not work. It need fully qualified repo name which also include `docker-id`.

Use

```
repository: '<docker-id>/<repo-name>'
```

instead of

```
repository: '<repo-name>'
```

Pipeline snippet:

```
- task: Docker@2
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: 'service-connection-name'
    repository: '<docker-id>/<repo-name>'
```

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Change privacy mode in the docker account

> https://hub.docker.com/settings/default-privacy
> [image]

Step 2: Run the below commands which are mentioned in the screenshort:

[image]

- docker images
- docker tag <<TAG_ID>> <<USER_NAME>>/<<IMAGE_NAME>>:latest
- docker login docker.io
- docker push <<USER_NAME>>/<<IMAGE_NAME>>:latest

output:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If it still fails after `docker login`, make sure the repository you're trying to push to was created in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

So, incase it is helpful to anyone...
I had this same issue and here is what my issue and the FIX was.

I had a computer on my test network named 'galaxy'.

I setup docker registry using the following run command:

```
sudo docker run -d 
--restart=always \
--name registry \
-v /srv/registry/certs:/certs \
-v /srv/registry/storage:/var/lib/registry \
-e REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:443 \
-e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/galaxy.cert \
-e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/galaxy.key \
-p 443:443 \
registry:2
```

Then I was trying to push an image to galaxy from a laptop on the network so I did this:

```
docker login galaxy
```

This would give me an error that would say:

```
Login did not succeed, error: Error response from daemon: 
    Get https://galaxy/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Oddly the fix to this issue was to do a login like this:

```
docker login galaxy:443
```

That resulted in a successful login.
So then I tried to push the image from my laptop to 'galaxy'.
I had already created a tag for my image that looked like this:

```
galaxy/myImage:0.0.1
```

So I tried to push it doing this:

```
docker push galaxy/myImage:0.0.1
```

To which I got the reply:

```
The push refers to repository [docker.io/galaxy/myImage]
7ab460574f86: Preparing 
1aecaf56754d: Preparing 
1df1b5f06ca4: Preparing 
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Oddly enough I discovered the fix for this was to first tag the image as follows:

```
docker tag myImage:0.0.1 galaxy:443/myImage:0.0.1
```

... and then do the push like this:

```
docker push galaxy:443/myImage:0.0.1
```

So for some reason I had to include the port in the tag as a required part of the repository name.

Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 1):

all previous answer were correct, I wanna just add an information I saw was not mentioned;

If the project is a private project to correctly push the image have to be configured a personal access token or deploy token with read_registry key enabled.

source: https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/container_registry#using-with-private-projects

hope this is helpful (also if the question is posted so far in the time)

Answer (score 1):

This answer is as much for my future self as for anyone else. I have encountered this exact problem when I am logged in correctly, but I am attempting to push to a private repo when my number of private repos is greater than or equal to the limit allowed by my plan.

I'm not exactly sure how I was able to create too many private repos, but if my plan includes 5 private repos, and somehow I have 6, then this is the error that I will receive:

`denied: requested access to the resource is denied`

In my case it's possible that I ended up with too many private repositories because I have my default visibility set to private:

[image: Default Visibility]

This is where you determine how many private repos you can have:

[image: Billing Plans]

Once I made the problematic repo public, the issue became apparent:

[image: Make Repository Private 5 of 5]

Answer (score 1):

I came here with the same above message, but from Azure DevOps.

In my case, I was using docker-compose, not just docker, and writing the build pipeline in yaml.

```
- task: DockerCompose@0
  displayName: 'Push services'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(Parameters.azureSubscriptionEndpoint)'
    azureContainerRegistry: '$(Parameters.azureContainerRegistry)'
    dockerComposeFile: '$(Parameters.dockerComposeFile)'
    additionalDockerComposeFiles: |
      docker-compose.release.yml
      docker-compose.ci.yml
    dockerComposeFileArgs: 'PublishFolder=publish'
    action: 'Push services'
    additionalImageTags: '$(Build.BuildId)'
    includeLatestTag: true
```

The message I got was specifically saying that it was trying to push to docker.io, which was not what I wanted. I had intended this to go to my Azure Container Registry.

Thing that was missing was this line under inputs:

```
containerregistrytype: Azure Container Registry
```

The existing pipeline wizard that built the yaml above did not have this line at all.
Hopefully this helps someone else pulling their hair out over Azure DevOps.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR `docker login` did not work for me on macOS but docker login from the app worked**

When used directly from the terminal, the command `docker login` successfully asked for my credentials and after I entered them correctly (remember no email, only the docker ID will work) it announced `login succeeded` but any request to push would end up in a `denied: requested access to the resource is denied`

However, when I logged in from the macOs docker app that was running (cf from the icon in the toolbar) it worked. So there may be some inconsistence between `docker login` and the running docker app/daemon

Answer (score 1):

Do not allow mislead towards tag name.
My approach to solve this:

```
Command 1(Create Tag): docker tag my-nginx:latest rsachde/nginx-repository/trys:1.0 (Didn't push)
Command 2(Push): docker push rsachde/nginx-repository/try:1.0
```

Output:

> denied: requested access to the resource is denied

---

```
Command 1.1(Create Tag): docker tag my-nginx:latest rsachde/nginx-repository/:trys 
Command 2.2(Push): docker push rsachde/nginx-repository:trys
```

Output:

> trys: digest:
>   sha256:405b6f0ae25772ef71b8f59fd6a56ff9b426f50bd24bac2b5db41f65efd3387c
>   size: 1365

Misleading is Tag, make sure you understand that.

Answer (score 1):

After giving each of the high score solution a try, I still got no luck.

Not until I changed my focus and search keyword to include my credential helper - pass.

If this is a similar case for you (using any kind of docker-credential-helpers and just followed a general guideline to setup), try to review the steps and see if anything has been missed.

For example, I'm using *pass* as the credstore for docker, the step to insert my dockerhub account password for a dedicated *pass-name* `docker-credential-helpers/docker-pass-initialized-check` had been missed when I just followed the top search results to setup *pass*.

After issuing the following command, `docker push` finally showed some mercy on me.

```
pass insert docker-credential-helpers/docker-pass-initialized-check
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52881198/5752875) for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't thought this step was crucial, I thought that was a random custom entry name and a random password.

Answer (score 1):

This might be very specific to DigitalOceans Container Registry but maybe it helps:

In my case my pipeline triggers a cleanup job (`doctl registry garbage-collection start`) after the `docker push` , which put the registry in read only mode (see [doc](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/container-registry/how-to/clean-up-container-registry/#considerations)). So the next push while the cleanup job is active will get `denied: requested access to the resource is denied`.

If `doctl registry garbage-collection get-active` returns a 404 the job finished and `docker push` will complete successfully.

Comment: This ended up being the same issue for me. I didn't realize that garbage-collection triggered read-only mode so I was scratching my head at the error message. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

#### Push all tags

use `-a` to push. s.t. `docker push username/image -a`

access denied is likely due to docker repository permission not public (u can double check)

U need to pull to check if it's ok.

#### View in hub.docker.com

Open 'Tags' to view all available tags after success push

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that finally worked for me was creating a public repository in docker hub and tagging the local image with the same name, and adding my userID in collaborators {in dockerhub} and finally pushing it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are already logged in and still if you get the error. Please follow the steps,

```
PS C:\Users\rohit\Docker> docker logout
Removing login credentials for https://index.docker.io/v1/

PS C:\Users\rohit\Docker> docker login
Login with your Docker ID to push and pull images from Docker Hub. If you don't have a Docker ID, head over to https://hub.docker.com to create one.
Username: rohithpoya
Password:*****************
Login Succeeded

Logging in with your password grants your terminal complete access to your account.
For better security, log in with a limited-privilege personal access token. Learn more at https://docs.docker.com/go/access-tokens/

PS C:\Users\rohit\Docker> docker push rohithpoya/mongo-enterprise:5                                                                                                                                                                       
The push refers to repository [docker.io/rohithpoya/mongo-enterprise]                                                                                                                                                                        83ee27b8fe98: Pushed
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue while creating a CI pipeline in Azure Devops to build and push docker image to Docker Hub. The mistake that I was making was providing wrong entry in Container repository section.

In buildAndPush task I was giving repository name in Container repository field. Actually repository name should be appended with Docker Hub username/.
So for example, your username is myuser and repository name is test then provide entry as myuser/test. As soon as I corrected this, the pipeline worked successfully and image was pushed to my docker hub repository

Answer (score 0):

rename your image to username/image-name 
 docker tag your-current-image/current-image dockerhub-username/some-name:your-tag(example: latest)

Answer (score 0):

Try sign out of "Docker for Windows" application and sign out of https://hub.docker.com/ site and after perform "docker login" and "docker push".
It helped for me.

Answer (score 0):

docker login from the command prompt did not work.  I kept getting "requested access to the resource is denied" when trying to push.

After signing in to the docker for windows  app itself, docker push worked just fine.   Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this - the cause, in my case, was that I was using the (deprecated) `docker compose` approach to push images.  Switching to the expected `docker push` resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another (pretty smart) reason for this: you're out of private repos with your plan.

Answer (score 0):

In my case sudo -E failed with this message. The resolution was to provide access do docker without sudo (create a group docker, add the (Jenkins) user to the group, set the group on /var/run/docker.sock). Now `docker push` does not need sudo, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

My problem on git was the project permission configuration.
I've fixed it by enable the "Container registry" in settings->general->Visibility, project features, permissions and enable Container Registry for my project ([link](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/index.html#sharing-and-permissions)):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Docker hub plans have restrictions on number of private repositories that a namespace can use. For instance, the free plan will only allow you to use one private repository at any point in time for an account.

If you are under your plan limits, then your push will succeed. Otherwise, an empty repository with an appropriate tag will be created but the image itself wont be pushed.

In my case, I created the repositories as public using the web console prior to pushing the images.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in ibmcloud. I added namespace and then tried to push my image, it resolved the issue.

```
ibmcloud cr namespace-add txts
```

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the docker push, both using the Fabric8 Maven plugin (on Windows 10), and directly calling `docker push` from the command line.

Finally I solved both issues the same way.

My repo is called vgrazi/playpen. In my pom, I changed the docker image name to vgrazi/playpen, as below:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
  <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.31.0</version>
  <configuration>
     <dockerHost>npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine</dockerHost>
     <verbose>true</verbose>
     <images>
       <image>
         <name>vgrazi/playpen</name>
         <build>
           <dockerFileDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/docker/</dockerFileDir>
                         ...
```

That let me do a `mvn clean package docker:build docker:push` from the command line, and at last, the image appeared in my repo, which was the problem I was trying to solve.

As an aside, to answer the OP and get this to work directly from the command line, without Maven, I did the following (PS is the PowerShell prompt, don't type that):

```
PS docker images
vgrazi/docker-test/docker-play                playpen             0722e876ebd7        40 minutes ago      536MB
rabbitmq                                      3-management        68055d63a993        10 days ago         180MB
PS docker tag 0722e876ebd7 vgrazi:playpen
PS docker push vgrazi/playpen
```

and again, the image appeared in my docker.io: repo vgrazi/playpen

Answer (score 0):

Docker login parameters in `~/.docker/config.json` should be properly set (which is done automatically after login)

1) Login without passing *SERVER* parameter:

```
$ echo "<password>" | docker login -u foo --password-stdin
```

After successful login it results as follows in *~/.docker/config.json* and pushing image ***succeeds***.

```
***
"https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
    "auth": "YWNhcm***"
}
***
```

2) Login with passing *SERVER* parameter as `index.docker.io`

```
$ echo "<password>" | docker login index.docker.io -u foo --password-stdin
```

After successful login it results as follows in *~/.docker/config.json* and pushing image ***fails***.

```
***
"index.docker.io": {
    "auth": "YWNhcm***"
}
***
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. Unfortunately, the error was due to using **sudo** before docker push. Also you might need to remove the repositories from dockerhub since there is a limit for the number of repos which you can have. And, please try `docker logout` and then `docker login`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, i resolved it by creating a repository with the same image name and then pushed it to the docker, it worked

Answer (score 0):

Here step

```
 1. Logout in Dockerhub website
 2. Login Dockerhub web
 3. Login Dockerhub  desktop
 4. Open with Dockerhub desktop
 5. re push it working well!
```

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck in the same issue but how I fixed I will share the step. The step which I was doing I was using wrong Docker ID while creating the tag. I found out that Docker ID is the username while we register on Docker Hub.

Follow the below link & follow the instructions step by step:
[Push the Docker image](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/04_sharing_app/#push-the-image)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue when deploying a `NestJS` application.

So, I followed these steps:

1. logged in to https://hub.docker.com/ in web and validated the namespace. (You can find it under repositories tab)
2. In terminal, typed `docker login`, In my case, it said, validating with existing credentials, otherwise just put the credentials.
3. Now created the image using the namespace I got in step 1. `docker build -t <<namespace name>>/<<your image name that you want to keep>>:<<version>> .` (note: there is code at the end of command)
4. pushed to docker using `docker push <<namespace name>>/<<your image name that you want to keep>>:<<version>>`
5. You can see the image in the docker hub.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GitLab's private container registry and fail to push to it, make sure that you give your project access token the "write_registry" scope and at "Developer" role!
If the role is just "Guest", which is the default, the scope can be as overkill as you want (I tried even "API" scope), but pushing won't work!

Reference: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html#project-members-permissions

Answer (score 0):

in my case, after spending some time investigating,  the issue was with the keychain of mac OS for some reason.

so depending on where the password gets stored (refer to this [link](https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/login/) for reference) , the config file `~/.docker/config.json` can either look like one of the following:

**1.** If no keychain used , the password will be stored directly in the file ,
example :

```
{
    "auths": {
        "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
            "auth": "base64-encode-of-your-credentials"
        }
    }
}
```

**2.** If a key chain is used then the credentials will not be saved in the file and the credsStore will be mentioned in the file  ,so will look something like this :

```
{
  "credsStore" : "osxkeychain",
  "auths" : {
    "https://index.docker.io/v1/" : {

    }
  }
}
```

In my case a cred store was being used and apparently there was something wrong with it even when I `docker logout` and `docker login` again  , in which case 2 different solutions have worked for me:

**1.** Edit the config file and remove the  `"credsStore" : "osxkeychain"` element and also add the `"auth"` element along with the base64 encoding of your creds from the format `username:password` , this way you are telling docker I am directly using the credentials from the file and no key store used , of course this method is less secure.

**2.** I opened the keychain access in my mac ( by searching for keychain access in the spotlight search) , then inside there I searcher for docker to see the credentials , upon opening it and ticking show password I found that the value was empty (not sure why) , so I manually put it there and clicked saved changes .

and voila after applying any of above solutions , the docker push command worked normally.

Answer (score -3):

I had the exact same issue. I would highly recommend to go through [this blog](https://blog.hildenco.com/2020/10/pushing-docker-images-to-azure.html).

My issue was more related to ACR. docker client would refer to the config.json file were your SP credential file would be stored (Role Owner).

Sections of the blog that helped me in the solution are:

> - docker image ls
> - docker tag .azurecr.io/:v1
> - docker push .azurecr.io/:v1

Before this action I also created a SP with the owner privilege.