# Gitlab CI + Docker Hub: requested access to the resource is denied

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to push my image to my docker repositoy repository using gitlab-ci, but i'm receiving the error:

**denied: requested access to the resource is denied
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1**

My *.gitlab-ci.yml*

```
# This file is a template, and might need editing before it works on your project.
# Official docker image.
image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

before_script:
   - docker version
   - docker-compose version
   - docker login -u $USER -p $PASS index.docker.io


build-master:
  stage: build
  script:
    - apk add --no-cache py-pip
    - pip install docker-compose    
    - docker build --pull -t index.docker.io/$REPOSITORY .
    - docker push index.docker.io/$REPOSITORY
  only:
    - master
  tags:
  - docker

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build --pull -t index.docker.io/$REPOSITORY:latest .
    - docker push index.docker.io/$REPOSITORY:latest
  except:
    - master
  tags:
  - docker
```

He build the image correctly, but when go to push

```
The push refers to repository [docker.io/$REPOSITORY]
fc57a6fc4d42: Preparing
09b261acf68f: Preparing
04ea2928643d: Preparing
1132926ce5ae: Preparing
de09db5a8cb2: Preparing
0b75a2e7b59f: Preparing
d01d9d1902f1: Preparing
3dab7cdf2eed: Preparing
1da4e8fff32b: Preparing
23c522961836: Preparing
a51421a28d33: Preparing
8b1c06910686: Preparing
30e8a3d88591: Preparing
fd8fae5cd65a: Preparing
6b68dfad3e66: Preparing
cd7100a72410: Preparing
0b75a2e7b59f: Waiting
d01d9d1902f1: Waiting
3dab7cdf2eed: Waiting
1da4e8fff32b: Waiting
23c522961836: Waiting
a51421a28d33: Waiting
8b1c06910686: Waiting
30e8a3d88591: Waiting
fd8fae5cd65a: Waiting
6b68dfad3e66: Waiting
cd7100a72410: Waiting
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I change the repository name for the $REPOSITORY only for paste here.

I already give the right permissions on hub.docker.com for the user has make the docker login, has a colaborator on the repository.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [denied: requested access to the resource is denied : docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984399/denied-requested-access-to-the-resource-is-denied-docker)

Comment: I am running up against this too.
Weirdly, the login works fine; $ docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin. WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /root/.docker/config.json. Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store Login Succeeded It almost looks related to this https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/23339 but I think this might be another issue. Are you able to push from

Comment: `$REPOSITORY` is probably the issue.

Comment: Just in passing...if you set `image` to `tmaier/docker-compose:latest` at the top of your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, you won't have to install pip and then install Docker Compose.

Answer (score 6):

use `$CI_REGISTRY` and `$CI_PROJECT_PATH`.

**Example code:**

```
- docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY/$CI_PROJECT_PATH
- docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY/$CI_PROJECT_PATH/name:latest
- docker push $CI_REGISTRY/$CI_PROJECT_PATH/name:latest
```

Comment: These predefined variables work like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is having the login within the `before_script` and not in the actual `script` section of the task.

It's a shame because it feels more 'correct' to me to factor the login part to the `before_script` section, and then to perform whatever Docker Hub-related actions are necessary in the `script` section.

But I'm afraid it doesn't work--each `script` section will need to include its own login step.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and i have changed "REGISTRY" varaibles adress which your registry address for example  " registry.gitlab.com/ayil****/emre***** " then the problem is solved.....