# How do you fix a docker push error, tag does not exist?

Tags: docker

When pushing a docker image to registry, I got this message:

```
docker push -t domain.com/repo/tag_docker_name:latest

Error tag name does not exist
```

The only way is to create the tag in docker repository via web interface, and then docker push works.

Is there a command line to create docker push?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [denied: requested access to the resource is denied : docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984399/denied-requested-access-to-the-resource-is-denied-docker)

Comment: Don't use -t. Try without -t. Also, try providing a port number after domain.com

Comment: How do you create the tag in docker repository via web interface?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to add a tag to the image, [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/) is the documentation.
Use it like this `docker tag 0e5574283393 domain.com/repo/tag_docker_name:latest` where 0e5574283393 is the image hash

Comment: Tag is already added to the image.
Problem is docker registry server which does not recognize this tag....

Comment: I misspelled the tag, so when I tried to push with the correct tag name, it couldn't find it (because it didn't exist locally). Make sure your local tag spelling matches the tag you're trying to push.

Answer (score 12):

If you have not tagged your image while docker build and added tag on push, you will get this error.

In my case, I haven't tagged the image and while build but push command added tag, that is why I was getting this error. below is my correct command

```
docker image build -t pankajrawat333/samplewebapp:v1 .
docker image push pankajrawat333/samplewebapp:v1
```

Comment: Or _someone_ had a different tag in the push command than the one tagged on build... not me of course. Thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 6):

First there is no option `-t` for `docker push` command

Second assume that you already have a tagged image said `repo/your_image:tag`, you should follow the push syntax `docker push repo/your_image:tag`, docker host should not be included (in your case `domain.com`) unless you want to push the image to a private repository.

A simple way to check whether the image name existed is to use `docker images`, which lists all images available on the host, and image name should be the same as displayed in `REPOSITORY` column.

Follow this [link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/) to check docker documentation

Comment: documentation link is broken.

Answer (score 3):

The official usage is below:

```
docker push < IMAGENAME >:< TAGNAME >
```

Answer (score 2):

sudo docker tag (imagename or hash)(dockerhubaccountname or id)/(repositoryname):(give the tag name like v1)

eg - sudo docker tag myimage5 hitanshug/testrep:v1

then run this command
docker push hitanshug/testrep:v1 , always remember the tag v1 to mention it in both commands.

And if you want to push in a private repo, then first do Docker login, give the credentials, and run all the above commands.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).