# Docker: Tag does not exist

Tags: docker, dockerhub, docker-push

I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49834454/docker-push-error-tag-does-not-exist) Stackoverflow question prior to asking this but even though it looks similar that question does not contain the answer for my matter.

I developed Springboot project and created docker image called `kubernatesimage` in my local machine. So when I run `docker images` it will list down all the images which I have locally,

```
REPOSITORY                         TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
kubernatesimage                    latest    0280b64ac863   15 hours ago    557MB
solr                               latest    e6b43a626b70   3 weeks ago     520MB
apache/zeppelin                    0.9.0     4e276fc244de   5 weeks ago     4.6GB
cassandra                          latest    8baadf8d390f   6 weeks ago     405MB
suhothayan/hadoop-spark-pig-hive   2.9.2     671a17ccce40   18 months ago   2.63GB
loliconneko/oracle-ee-11g          latest    b1ed15c38b8c   24 months ago   5GB
```

Then I referred [this](https://ropenscilabs.github.io/r-docker-tutorial/04-Dockerhub.html) documentation to pull my docker image into dockerhub. So I tagged the image and pushed it by following commands,

```
docker tag 0280b64ac863 semicolon10/kubernatesimage:firsttry 

docker push semicolon10/kubernatesimage
```

But it results an error,

> The push refers to repository [docker.io/semicolon10/kubernatesimage]
> tag does not exist: semicolon10/kubernatesimage:latest

Here one thing I noticed is that after docker tag it will create another docker image locally with the assigned tag,

```
REPOSITORY                         TAG        IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
kubernatesimage                    latest     0280b64ac863   15 hours ago    557MB
semicolon10/kubernatesimage        firsttry   0280b64ac863   15 hours ago    557MB
solr                               latest     e6b43a626b70   3 weeks ago     520MB
apache/zeppelin                    0.9.0      4e276fc244de   6 weeks ago     4.6GB
cassandra                          latest     8baadf8d390f   6 weeks ago     405MB
suhothayan/hadoop-spark-pig-hive   2.9.2      671a17ccce40   18 months ago   2.63GB
loliconneko/oracle-ee-11g          latest     b1ed15c38b8c   24 months ago   5GB
```

**Note**: I have successfully logged into my dockerhub account and my dockerhub username is `semicolon10`. So please can someone point out the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should:

```
docker tag 0280b64ac863 docker.io/semicolon10/kubernatesimage:firsttry
```

Then push:

```
docker push docker.io/semicolon10/kubernatesimage:firsttry
```

Note include the repository : `docker.io`

Comment: Hello, This results the same error-`tag does not exist: semicolon10/kubernatesimage:latest` and one thing I noticed is that in my docker hub new image is creating named `semicolon10/kubernatesimage` locally

Comment: after `docker tag`  do `docker images` to see all images on localhost ? Please show `docker images` here

Comment: `kubernatesimage                    latest     0280b64ac863   15 hours ago    557MB
semicolon10/kubernatesimage        firsttry   0280b64ac863   15 hours ago    557MB
solr                               latest     e6b43a626b70   3 weeks ago     520MB
apache/zeppelin                    0.9.0      4e276fc244de   6 weeks ago     4.6GB
cassandra                          latest     8baadf8d390f   6 weeks ago     405MB
suhothayan/hadoop-spark-pig-hive   2.9.2      671a17ccce40   18 months ago   2.63GB
loliconneko/oracle-ee-11g          latest     b1ed15c38b8c   24 months ago   5GB`

Comment: do `docker tag 0280b64ac863 docker.io/semicolon10/kubernatesimage:firsttry` include `docker.io`

Comment: Yes I did sir but it results the same error

Comment: I added `:firsttry` at the end of docker push command and it worked