# Docker Push has failed in Red Hat Server with error "**denied: requested access to the resource is denied**"

Tags: docker, redhat

I am new bee to docker concepts . I have been trying the samples of creating images and push in docker hub on red hat server. 
I used below command to push my image to hub (**Note :**  i dont have any special char to my image name)

```
docker push registry.hub.docker.com/ssqaapt/first-img-sample
```

I am facing an below error when I push the image to docker hub repo .

```
    [root@p01 simple-web-app]# docker push registry.hub.docker.com/ssaapt/wipro-first-img-sample
The push refers to a repository [registry.hub.docker.com/ssaapt/first-img-sample]
673be84d418c: Preparing
....
b6a02001ba33: Waiting
....
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

I tried the push after i have logged my docker acc using ths cmd `docker login` .
Please suggest me if i have done anything wrong or do i need any configuration change .
I verified this link([denied: requested access to the resource is denied : docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984399/denied-requested-access-to-the-resource-is-denied-docker)) as well but no luck .

Comment: Your log message says you're pushing to a Red Hat server, not to official Docker Hub.

Comment: @DavidMaze so do i change the docker push command . if so please let me know

Comment: @DavidMaze i have followed one tutorial , they did not mention explicitly mapping for docker hub in command .

Comment: docker tag ssqaapt/dlkdfdf registry.hub.docker.com/ssqaapt/dlkdfdf and then docker push registry.hub.docker.com/ssqaapt/dlkdfdf

Comment: which version of docker you are using

Comment: @Adiii , I tried the command which you suggested . i got different one now 'denied: requested access to the resource is denied
'

Comment: do you have right access to this image?

Comment: @Adiii the version of my docker is 1.13

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179013/discussion-between-sakthisureshanand-and-adiii).

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to /etc/containers/registries.conf
2. Add/Replace ‘registry.hub.docker.com’ for [registries.search] and [registries.insecure]section.
3. Restart your docker

   - $ systemctl stop docker
   - $ systemctl start docker
   - $ docker login-

     4. Execute the push command and it should work.