# Why can I not push new docker build to DockerHub repo

Tags: docker, dockerhub

So I create a Docker hub image as follows, worked fine

```
Created new empty repository in DockerHub
Uploaded my DockerFile to my webserver
ssh *qnapserver*
docker build *DockerFileUrl*
docker login *DockerHubUsername* *DockerHubPassword*
docker images (to get imageId of built image)
docker tag *imageId* *DockerHubNameSpace*/*DockerHubRepository*:latest
docker push *DockerHubNameSpace*/*DockerHubRepository*:latest
```

A few weeks later I need to rebuild image for new software version, so I did

```
ssh *qnapserver*
docker build *DockerFileUrl*
docker login *DockerHubUsername* *DockerHubPassword*
docker images (to get imageId of built image)
docker tag *imageId* *DockerHubNameSpace*/*DockerHubRepository*:latest
docker push *DockerHubNameSpace*/*DockerHubRepository*:latest
```

but the final push command fails with

```
The push refers to a repository [docker.io/songkong/songkong-arm32]
d68f3fa1b903: Preparing
a0fcc8fd26d0: Preparing
e921eb3da019: Preparing
30b60a45df09: Preparing
8a9717d91a27: Preparing
fcf19287cca0: Waiting
72b719a20b26: Waiting
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Running docker images gives:

```
[~] # docker images
REPOSITORY                TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
songkong/songkong-arm32   latest              d2ab52ce970a        14 minutes ago      179MB
arm32v6/openjdk           8-jre-alpine        d6163b61a7aa        8 days ago          72.9MB
songkong/songkong-arm32   <none>              a57032901b5c        2 weeks ago         169MB
songkong/songkong-arm32   <none>              8f3ae4b75feb        2 weeks ago         162MB
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [denied: requested access to the resource is denied : docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984399/denied-requested-access-to-the-resource-is-denied-docker)

Comment: @AmmoPT the answer says I need to tag image, but I have done so dont underdtand what Im doing wrong ?

Comment: @AmmoPT okay the problem seems to be my docker login was incorrect, if i just entered docker login and retyped username and a password the push then worked

Comment: Hey nice to know, you might wanna reply to your own answer and accept it, it might help others. Have a good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be that I wasnt logged onto  DockerHub properly

```
docker login *DockerHubUsername* *DockerHubPassword*
```

did not return an error, but I tried doing

```
docker login
```

and entering *username* and *password* at the prompt and then the push worked ok.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Docker for Mac ?

There is a bug with the `docker login` CLI command.

Please see this github issue and add your experience if you can :

https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2016