# Docker requested access to the resource is denied

Tags: docker

I've read [denied: requested access to the resource is denied : docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984399/denied-requested-access-to-the-resource-is-denied-docker) and I do the same but the access is still denied.

```
docker tag my_image my_name/rep:tag
docker push my_name/rep:tag
```

But i get

```
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

I guess the problem is in

```
docker login
```

if I enter incorrect password I get

```
incorrect username or password
```

if I enter correct password I get
[image]
I do not see

```
login succeeded
```

I tried

```
docker login -u username -p password
```

and get

```
Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin
```

I try use --password-stdin and get the same

- I use windows 8 and Docker version 18.09.3

Comment: you could try using `docker login -u username -p password` and check if you get `Login succeeded`. Also try doing it from normal cmd.

Comment: In this case I get `Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin` I try use --password-stdin and get the same

Comment: @michalk THANKS! it was made by using `Git Bash`

Comment: @Ikar0 Read his post carefully, he already checked that question with no luck. The problem was, he was using GitBash.

Answer (score 0):

I use `Git Bash`  - thanks @michalk 
Through `Git Bash` it seems

```
$ docker login -u usename -p password
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in C:\Users\..............docker\config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to push the docker image on dockerHub & getting the error

> denied: requested access to the resource is denied

1. You just need to write a CMD `docker login` on running console
2. Prompted to insert your

- DockerHub `username`: write your username
- DockerHub `Password`: write your password

You will get a msg

> Login Succeeded

3. After this step you can push your Docker image on DockerHub with `docker push` command.