# Confusion about failure of pulling images from docker registry

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers

I have two images tar-ed. Now, I docker load -i each of them into the registry, so it looks like something bellow, mongo and cloud_docker_app.

[image]

With help of yaml, it's easy to run mongo correctly--thus I think I can say that I am corretly docker login-ing since the mongo image can be pulled successfully as files show.

[image]

[image]

But, I cannot pull cloud_docker_app at all. This confuses me much especially when I am login-ing and the image (cloud_docker_app) exists.
[image]

[image]

I have tried https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/ or delete ~/.docker/config.json and re-login, but it doesn't help at all. Any ideas are welcome and appreciated.

Comment: `docker images` doesn't show things in a Docker registry, it shows images on a local machine.  You need to `docker push` the image to a registry and then reference it in your deployment YAML.  `docker load` isn't part of a typical Kubernetes workflow.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems that it's required to docker push (to the docker official registry) before using any images. Is it possible to change this work flow by pushing images to other registries instead of the docker official one?

Comment: Sure, AWS ECR, quay.io, Google GCR, ... work fine, but you have to explicitly put the fully-qualified `quay.io/foo/bar:tag` name in the deployment spec.

Answer (score 1):

After referring to [denied: requested access to the resource is denied : docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984399/denied-requested-access-to-the-resource-is-denied-docker) and change the image path in yaml to be $(docker hub account)/$(folders if any)/$IMAGE, the image is found.

Thanks a lot for David Maze's help and information.