# Push to docker repository fail on AzurePipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-tasks

The task `Docker push` fail to push the image into docker hub.

The yml:

```
steps:
- task: Docker@0
  displayName: 'Push an image'
  inputs:
    containerregistrytype: 'Container Registry'
    dockerRegistryConnection: 'docker hub'
    action: 'Push an image'
```

The log:

```
Starting: Push an image
==============================================================================
Task         : Docker
Description  : Build, tag, push, or run Docker images, or run a Docker command
Version      : 0.157.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker
==============================================================================
dbef9fd1-06fb-47eb-af36-bf86b4d44152 exists true
"C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe" push azuretp:38
The push refers to repository [docker.io/library/azuretp]
f2369ebe2bed: Preparing
...
537ddf9b819a: Waiting
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
##[error]C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe failed with return code:
```

The connection `docker hub` is correct. I just reenter the credentials and Azure pipeline validate it successfully.

The problem seams to be with the path, according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984399/denied-requested-access-to-the-resource-is-denied-docker), but i can't find a way to specify my docker hub name within this task.

Comment: I think you need to create a connection for your docker hub first.

Comment: The problem, is with the image itself. The image tag has to change in order to match repository. Probably won't need to do it if i use azure registry instead docker registry service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The push refers to repository [docker.io/library/azuretp]

According to this error message line, seems the task is pushing image to the root level of Docker hub, which is not allowed.

---

To solve it, please change the task from `0.*` to `2.*`

And then, input your docker repository name which listed in the [Docker repository page](https://hub.docker.com/repositories) by using the format: `dockerhub_namespace/RepositoryName`:

[image]

[image]

For YAML, please use below sample:

```
steps:
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: push
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: {service connection name}
    repository: {dockerhub_namespace/RepositoryName}
    command: push
```

Comment: I was not aware that i could pick a different implementation for the task. One suggestion to Microsoft, make the last version the default. Thank you.