# How to push an image to Docker Hub in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-pipelines

I'd like to push my image to Docker Hub. [Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/containers/push-image?view=azure-devops#push-step-in-pipeline) seems to be simple, yet I lost with details.

```yaml
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Push image
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: |
      $(dockerHub)
    repository: username/repo
    command: push
    tags: latest
```

What should be the value of `$(dockerHub)` variable and how to construct it? These [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-docreg) seem to explain it, but I don't get it.

Comment: Not get your latest information. Just want to check whether below answer is helpful for you? If yes, you can accept the answer and we could archive this thread. Also, feel free to leave comment below if still has any puzzle about it:-)

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT Thanks for the answer was helpful. I decided to edit it because I spent significant amount of time locating elements in UI. And it was not obvious for me since these are my first days with Azure DevOps interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set up a `Docker Registry` in project settings `service connections`. To do so follow below instructions:

1. Go to https://dev.azure.com/my_username
2. Click project that you working on.
3. Click `Project Settings` - There should be a gear icon in down left corner on a web page.
4. Click `Service connections` -In the middle of the page in **Pipeline settings** section.
5. Click `New service connection` button - in upper right corner
6. Select `Docker Registry` - click next
7. Choose `Docker Hub` option as registry type.
8. Provide `Docker ID` - docker hub **username**, **password** and set `Service connection name` to **dockerHub**.

[image]

Once this is done then you set **dockerHub** in `Docker@2` task in [yaml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops#login) file. e.g. `containerRegistry: dockerHub`

Alternatively this method should work as well.
Select the Docker registry service connection in the docker task:

[image]

[image]

Comment: BTW. I ended up following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984399/denied-requested-access-to-the-resource-is-denied-docker#answer-41984666) in order to push my image to Docker Hub.