# denied: requested access to the resource is denied in Ubuntu

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, devops

I am using ubuntu 16.04 in virtual box. I have successfully install Docker `Docker version 20.10.5, build 55c4c88` 
[image]

I have try all commands to push my image docker hub but failed. Every time I got same issue `denied: requested access to the resource is denied`

please help me out....

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41984666/4676641) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

It is clear from the error `denied: requested access to the resource is denied` means you do not have the permission to push. So first you need to get the permission to push. And to do that, before pushing to docker hub, you need to do:

`docker login --username=<your_docker_hub_username>`

and then:

`docker push <your_docker_hub_name>/<your_image_name>:<image_tag>`

Comment: still denied : requested.......I am fade up with this issue. I don't know why this is so much complication in this task.

Comment: @ShivamChauhan then first do `docker logout` and then again do login, you can try this!

Comment: Now, I go with another approach and got success

Comment: @ShivamChauhan, What was the other approach with which you got success? I'm currently stuck on the same issue