# How to resolve 'denied: requested access to the resource is denied' error when pushing a Docker image to Docker Hub?

Tags: docker

docker push error "denied: requested access to the resource is denied", I have no idea to solve this

I'm trying to push an image to docker hub but when I do the command "docker push docker/dockerfile" the error "denied: requested access to the resource is denied" is comming, I was thinking that the problem come because I wasn't log in, but I am already so idk.

Comment: Did you try to follow instructions from https://stackoverflow.com/a/41984666/18781306?