Unable to push Docker image to Docker Hub from AWS EC2 instance ( Error: requested access to the resource is denied )
I am facing an issue when trying to push a Docker image from my AWS EC2 instance to Docker Hub. Here are the steps I followed:

Logged into Docker on my EC2 instance using docker login.
Built the Docker image using docker build <user_name>/<repo_name>.
Created the repository on Docker Hub.
Attempted to push the image using docker push <user_name>/<repo_name>.

However, I encountered the following error:
The push refers to repository [docker.io/<user_name>/<repo_name>]
7abfb0741b3d: Preparing 
3773452b6e48: Preparing 
8789db06fb83: Preparing 
25e1b6e594d0: Preparing 
0e87b211f7ef: Preparing 
9b87c194c4dd: Waiting 
1f00ff201478: Waiting 
denied: requested access to the resource is denied

I have ensured that the outbound rules in the security group allow all traffic, and I have successfully pushed the same image from my local system using the same steps.
Could someone please help me troubleshoot this issue? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

If you're getting this far, it doesn't suggest an issue with AWS security groups or anything else network-related.  You're connecting to Docker Hub, but it's telling you that you don't have access to push.  Did you docker login on the remote machine?

Yah, I have logged into my docker hub account in the remote machine.

Did you check answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984399/denied-requested-access-to-the-resource-is-denied-docker?
