# How to overcome access to resource denied for docker push in official tutorial

Tags: docker, push

I googled and saw this but I don't know what it is saying about image tags, etc:  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984399/denied-requested-access-to-the-resource-is-denied-docker)

I am trying to complete the tutorial here: [tutorial official Docker](https://docker-curriculum.com/)

Here is my output for `docker images`

```
nobu@nobu-ThinkPad-T420:~/docker/docker-curriculum/flask-app$ docker images
REPOSITORY                TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
prakhar1989/catnip        latest              517dbced092c        About an hour ago   700MB
nginx                     latest              06144b287844        2 weeks ago         109MB
busybox                   latest              e1ddd7948a1c        7 weeks ago         1.16MB
prakhar1989/catnip        <none>              c984660fe008        7 weeks ago         700MB
hello-world               latest              2cb0d9787c4d        2 months ago        1.85kB
python                    3-onbuild           292ed8dee366        2 months ago        691MB
prakhar1989/static-site   latest              f01030e1dcf3        2 years ago         134MB
```

What I don't understand is which column above shows the image name?  I see a column for repo and then for ID but neither seems to fit the bill and the tutorial skips over this key piece of info.

I was able to run the app on `localhost:8888`.

I don't know why I am getting:

```
nobu@nobu-ThinkPad-T420:~/docker/docker-curriculum/flask-app$ docker push prakhar1989/catnip
The push refers to repository [docker.io/prakhar1989/catnip]
f438d02b6568: Preparing 
0a0917397206: Preparing 
b24e1ed3eb49: Preparing 
29778035860f: Preparing 
fc88d2431f4d: Preparing 
1dc1b82fa010: Waiting 
09e3fd9cf357: Waiting 
138d1921c15b: Waiting 
d714f65bc280: Waiting 
fd6060e25706: Waiting 
d7ed640784f1: Waiting 
1618a71a1198: Waiting 
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

I have an account on Docker Hub and set up a public repository.
Can someone give me hints on what command I need to enter to push this?

Comment: This helped me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42300879/3333878

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a common mistake I make, thought this might help someone.

Make sure you are consistent in using `sudo` across login and push. .i.e:

1. `docker login` should always be followed by `docker push` and
2. `sudo docker login` should always be followed by `sudo docker push`

This is because of the config for `sudo docker` and `docker` are different files in the system.

Answer (score 5):

The creator of the tutorial forgot to mention we have to tag the image first with `docker tag {image ID number} yourhubusername/{name_of_your_choice]:firsttry`
where `:firsttry` is a tag (I'll post photos below).

Here is the terminal output from the above tagging and then `docker push`

```
nobu@nobu-ThinkPad-T420:~/docker/docker-curriculum/flask-app$ docker tag 0690a67d2358 hockeymonkey96/catnip:firsttry
nobu@nobu-ThinkPad-T420:~/docker/docker-curriculum/flask-app$ docker push hockeymonkey96/catnip
The push refers to repository [docker.io/hockeymonkey96/catnip]
9da301382602: Pushed 
40a74dab97c5: Pushed 
d27f618acc37: Pushed 
29778035860f: Mounted from prakhar1989/catnip 
fc88d2431f4d: Mounted from prakhar1989/catnip 
1dc1b82fa010: Mounted from prakhar1989/catnip 
09e3fd9cf357: Mounted from prakhar1989/catnip 
138d1921c15b: Mounted from prakhar1989/catnip 
d714f65bc280: Mounted from prakhar1989/catnip 
fd6060e25706: Mounted from prakhar1989/catnip 
d7ed640784f1: Mounted from prakhar1989/catnip 
1618a71a1198: Mounted from prakhar1989/catnip 
firsttry: digest: sha256:39193977dfe6474d77127aea2b249105669d0683988a3c7043ac66eb2264141e size: 2840
```

Now when I look at Docker Hub, I can see it:

[image]

And that `:firsttry` tag is here:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because your docker hub account is not login in your terminal

First login your docker account by using following command

```
sudo docker login
username: your username
password : your password
```

Second push your local repository into docker hub by using following command

```
sudo docker tag local-image:tagname reponame:tag
sudo docker push reponame:tag
```

eg. 
sudo docker tag tagId  dockerdemo:latest

sudo docker push dockerdemo:latest