# docker push failed. unauthorized: authentication required

Tags: docker, azure-devops

I am having a visual studio subscription. From that I am having a benefit of accessing azure devops. I have used docker container registry for image build and push, and it is successful. Now I have changed to Azure container registry, this time image build is successful, but push failed saying unauthorized access. See below error
**The push refers to repository [(registryname).azurecr.io/(myname)/myfirstproject]. unauthorized: authentication required**

I have tried to select Service Principal Authentication option, but saying

```
**Failed to create an app in Azure Active Directory. Error: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.**
```

So, I have used Managed Identity Authentication option, but the push image failed.

Is it like I have to use Service Principal Authentication option only to push the image in ACS or am I missing anything.
I can provide more information if required.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look at this conversation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36663742/docker-unauthorized-authentication-required-upon-push-with-successful-login

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. The above stackoverflow is for docker container registry. I am using azure container registry. Please can you guide me on azure container registry.

Comment: Hi Raja, you follow that guide https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/container-registry/container-registry-get-started-docker-cli? First u need login.